# how to prevent key navigation to focus on hidden(with ng-hide) tabs?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I'm working with angular version of kendoui [tabstrip](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tabstrip/index) widget

In my usecase part of tabs in the tabstrip are initially hidden and became visible only if user selects certain options from dropdown:

```
    <div class="wrap">
  <div id="tabstrip" kendo-tab-strip="tabstrip">
    <ul>
      <li class="k-state-active">Tab 1</li>
      <li ng-show="tabToHide!=='hide-second' && tabToHide!=='hide-second-and-third'">Tab 2</li>
      <li ng-show="tabToHide!=='hide-third' && tabToHide!=='hide-second-and-third'">Tab 3</li>
      <li>Tab 4</li>
    </ul>

    <div>
      Tab one content.
    </div>
    <div ng-show="tabToHide!=='hide-second && tabToHide!=='hide-second-and-third''">
      Tab two content. 
    </div>
    <div ng-show="tabToHide!=='hide-third' && tabToHide!=='hide-second-and-third'">
      Tab three content. 
    </div> 
    <div>
      Tab 444 content. 
    </div>    
  </div>

  <select ng-model="tabToHide">
     <option>show-all</option>
     <option>hide-second</option>
     <option>hide-third</option>
     <option>hide-second-and-third</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

My problem is: when navigating with arrow keys through the tabs the "invisible" tabs get focused. (when tab 1 active and tab2 hidden  and you trying to navigate to the right you must click twice for open tab3)

How to make only visible tabs focusable?

Thanks

here is [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DNwzMK0SppEh8sTbHYMJ?p=preview) that demosnstartes the problem

Comment: have you tried to disable the tab with the tabstrip disable function?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of solution/workaround i have found so far. I admit this not ideal:

```
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($compile, $scope, $timeout, moveVisibleTabSvc) {

    $scope.tabToHide = 'hide-second';
    $scope.tabStripOptions = {
        animation: false, 
        activate: function(e) { 

        moveVisibleTabSvc.checkIfHidden($(e.item), $scope.tabstrip);
        }
    }
  }).service('moveVisibleTabSvc',function moveVisibleTabSvc(){
      var prevItem;//for find direction
      function findNextVisible(hidden){
          var nxt = hidden.next();
          return nxt.is(':visible')?nxt:findNextVisible(nxt);
      }
      function findPrevVisible(hidden){
          var prv = hidden.prev();
          return prv.is(':visible')?prv:findPrevVisible(prv);
      }      
      function direction(curItem){

          return curItem.index() > prevItem.index() ?'right':'left';  

      }
      function moveToNextVisible(hidden) {        
            return direction(hidden) ==='right' ? findNextVisible(hidden) : findPrevVisible(hidden);        
      }
      function checkIfHidden(item, tabstrip){
          //if the first is hidden
            if(!prevItem){prevItem = item}

          var hidden = item;  
          if(item.hasClass('ng-hide')) {
              var tabToSelect = moveToNextVisible(hidden);             
              if(tabToSelect.length) { 

                  tabstrip.select(tabToSelect); 
              }
          }
          prevItem = tabToSelect || item; 
      }

      this.checkIfHidden = checkIfHidden;

    })
```

here is [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VTqGvgTsMVF463jjGxiu?p=preview)